# Carrusel en MVC ASP.NET con Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto ASP.NET MVC 5. Estoy tratando de implementar un carrusel de imágenes con las marcas con las que trabaja la empresa, dicho carrusel lo tome de la pagina de Bootstrap, la versión que estoy usando es la v4.0, una vez colocado el código del carrusel en el index de la página las imagenes aparecen una sobre otra y no a como se ve en la página de bootstrap.

Así es como se ve en mi proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como deseo que se vea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del carrusel:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/Imagenes/Grupo puma.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/Imagenes/Loctite.png" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/Imagenes/meta-logo-cemex.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estos son son los bundles y estilos que estan en el _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Hay algo que hace falta de agregar o corregir algo?
Quedo atento a sus sugerencias, gracias de antemano!!

Comment: El inspector de páginas es tu mejor herramienta, revisa que se estén cargando correctamente todas las librerías y no tengas algún error 404 por ahí

Comment: Voy a revisar y próximamente les estaré avisando!!,gracias!!!

Comment: Revisando el inspector, en apariencia todo se carga bien, no hay errores 404, pero no logro dar con la falla del slide....